# Ionic capacitor Operation not permitted in target CapacitorCordova

Tags: ios, capacitor

I recently start ionic project with a capacitor and i am trying to run it on IOS.
When i Try to build and run project in Xcode then i get:

```
error: open /Users/pc/Desktop/photo-gallery/node_modules/@capacitor/ios/CapacitorCordova/CapacitorCordova/Classes/Public/CDVAvailability.h: Operation not permitted (in target 'CapacitorCordova' from project 'Pods')
```

but I have no idea what it may depend on. I used the capacitor a few months ago and had no such problem before. I also try to remove and add Ios platform, sync project but without success

libs in packege.json:

```
"@capacitor/core": "^2.4.7",
"@capacitor/ios": "^2.4.7",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok and found solution. You need to add full disk access for Xcode.

Mac -> preferences -> security & privacy -> privacy -> unlock window and add Xcode for Full disk access.

Comment: This fix works on macOS 12.1 Monterey